# raw_input in defined Functions

Tags: python

This is a program to check fermat's theorem.The code takes the input but displays nothing.

```
def bam(dam):
    x="enter first digit"
    a=raw_input(x)
    int(a)
    y="enter second digit"
    b=raw_input(y)
    int(b)
    z="enter third digit"
    a=raw_input(z)
    int(b)
    g="enter power"
    n=raw_input(g)
    int(n
    )
def check_fermat(a,b,c,n):
    if n>2 and a**n+b**n==c**n:
        print "Holy Smokes Fermat was wrong!"
    else:
        print "N0, that doesnt work"

bam(check_fermat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never *call* `check_fermat()`. If `bam` is supposed to apply the inputs to the function, you forgot to add that call:

```
dam(int(a), int(b), int(c), int(n))
```

but you never assigned to `c` (you assigned to `b` twice instead).

All the `int()` calls in the `bam()` function can be removed; they don't do anything useful, because you are ignoring their return values.

If you used more meaningful names, `dam` could look like:

```
def take_input(func):
    a = int(raw_input("enter first digit"))
    b = int(raw_input("enter second digit"))
    c = int(raw_input("enter third digit"))
    n = int(raw_input("enter power"))
    return func(a, b, c, n)
```

and use that as:

```
take_input(check_fermat)
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for all that gibberish code. I am new to stackoverflow and python.

Comment: one thing I dont understand is how did the func object work in returning a,b,c and n

Comment: @user3378637: you pass a reference to the `check_fermat` function object into `take_input`; functions are objects too, just like strings and integers. In the `take_input` function, `func` is a reference to that function object, and `func()` calls the function.